# problem binding inside itemRender

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

ok guy I really need you super brain on this, I had pull out all my hair now, I just want to throw the towel on this one, ok, I have an itemrender component, which you can see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
   creationComplete="hbox1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import events.ColorsEvent;

   import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
   import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;
   import mx.events.ColorPickerEvent;
   import mx.events.FlexEvent;
   import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;

   import utils.BindingUniform;

   private var _op:ObjectProxy;
   private var cw:ChangeWatcher;

   public function get value():String
   {
    return data.color;
   }

   override public function set data(value:Object):void
   {
    super.data = value;
    cp.selectedColor = data.color;
   }

   protected function cp_changeHandler(event:ColorPickerEvent):void
   {
    _op[data.id] = event.color;
   }

   protected function hbox1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
   {
    if(_op == null){
     _op = BindingUniform.op;
     cw = BindingUtils.bindSetter(dispatchColorChange, _op, data.id);
    }
   }

   protected function dispatchColorChange(color:uint):void
   {
    cp.selectedColor = color;
    dispatchEvent(new ColorsEvent("colorChanged", color, data.id, true, true));
   }

  ]]>
 </mx:Script>
 <mx:Text width="145"><mx:text>{data.value}</mx:text></mx:Text>
 <mx:ColorPicker id="cp" dataProvider="{parentDocument.colorsDP}" 
     valueCommit="{data.color = cp.selectedColor}"
     change="cp_changeHandler(event)" editable="false"/>
 <mx:Label id="colorLb" text="{cp.selectedItem.label}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

the idea is when I change a color in one of the colorpicker then the change event must change a dynamic variable in my _op objectProxy object.

Ok when I scroll the list the colors remains in their respective colorpicker, which is ok, my problem comes in the binding, when the itemRender creationcomplete event fire, I make a bindsetter to the variable so I can dispatch an event when the property change.

The reason why I'm need the bind is because some times the user will load a previous saved model and I want the variables to remain bind so the colorpicker will select the color correctly, hope make sense.

Ok the thing is the first visible rows work just ok, but when I scroll the list, and try to change the color the color change in the colorpicker but my bind is gone, and if I scroll back to the top the first ones also aren't bind no more, I really don't know what else to do, I'm just hopping somebody has done something similar or just have the solution to this, please help me if you can, I really need it, I think my brain is going to explode, why binding is so hard in Flex? thanks!!!

Comment: wish I could help you but it's very hard to understand your question. try breaking it up into smaller parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `itemRenderer` should not reach outside itself to pull in data and especially not set values or participate in bindings or events.  It should only act on the `data` passed to it.  It can read values out of `data` or set values on `data` which can then be broadcast out to other components.

Programming this way, making your `itemRenderer` components fully encapsulated little black boxes, will greatly simplify development and generally work much better and avoid hard-to-find-and-debug problems like memory leaks and dangling item renderer references which can respond to evens even after you've long since thought they vanished.

Answer (score 1):

I only glanced through your code to see if there were poor practices with itemRenderers, and I have two suggestions.  First, as Sam mentioned, make your renderer a stand-alone component that doesn't depend upon your objectProxy object.  Use events to make changes to make model-related changes.

Second, and more importantly, this line is a killer:

> cp.selectedColor = data.color;

replace it with "value.color"

Comment: mmm, ok I wil do it thanks for your reply and yes I agree with both, I change my design and now I'm able to bind, thanks!!